# Horribly Bad Static In Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, sound, pulseaudio, skype, alsa

I've searched around the askubuntu site and no seems to be having a similar issue. Everyone's having problems with Skype, etc.. me? I'm just having a problem with REALLY bad microphone static. I uploaded an example of it to YouTube to give you an idea... (brace your ears!)

http://youtu.be/3fWXRr3KUHU

What could be causing this. It is NOTHING like this in Windows 7 or 8. Just Ubuntu. Hadn't really noticed it until today, because today was the first time I tried to use Skype on Ubuntu, and nearly blew out my friends eardrums! Please help!

Comment: How high is the volume of the microphone, and did you try to change it?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).